# Grub corrupted at last update in 14.04

Tags: dual-boot

I run Ubuntu 14.04 along with Windows 7 Home Premium but after the last update on Friday 3rd October Grub became corrupted and couldn't find Ubuntu but could find Windows. After several attempts at grub repair to no avail I ended up reinstalling Ubuntu to another part of the hard drive which is a pain as I had to obviously set it all up again, so far it works fine but I am hesitant to allow any updates in case this problem occurs again. There seemed to be lot of people talking on forums about this update problem so can you tell me if this bug has been fixed please.

Comment: Could you add more information, like a link to where people are discussing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Please  check the link and install boot repair

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair